# Data-Driven automation testing using different input files

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, data-driven-tests

I have done data-driven automation testing using excel and XML.
Is there any other input file that we can use for data-driven in automation testing for selenium-webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google docs spreadsheet is good. You could try that - multiple people will be able to manage the data in the spreadsheet at the same time.

Comment: Rather than Google docs, is there any other way for data-driven testing.

Comment: You could use a database if you wanted to get really technical. MySQL or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, can use any file for data.

For data, you have to write reading and writing code for that file format into your preferred language and then pass that data into selenium code.

You can design your framework of automation testing using various test framework that available for your preferred language like for java you can use JUnit, TestNG etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any input file format that Java(or any other language that you have chosen) supports. In order to achieve this you need to write utility functions to read/write the data from/to the file.

For this purpose you can use Java in-built classes such as 'Scanner' etc.,. or you can use external libraries to get the work done for you.

Specific to your question other than Excel, I have used 'OpenCSV' parser library for Java to read and write data from a .csv file. This is a very simple and yet powerful library to work with CSV files.

You can go through this article for a better understanding - [openCSV](http://howtodoinjava.com/3rd-party/parse-read-write-csv-files-opencsv-tutorial/)